# Reading in file contents separated by two lines into a list

Tags: python

I have a text file containing:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

and I want to read in the contents into a list in python. The issue I'm facing is that i want to ignore the number 5 which is on the first line in the file. The number 5 represents the number of elements below it which is 5. Instead, i want to only append 1,2,3,4,5 into a list.

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I tried this:

```
file = open('text.txt','r')
textfile = file
lst = []

for line in textfile:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    line[1] = int(line[1])         #convert 1,2,3,4,5 into integers
    lst.append(line[1])
print(lst)
```

The error I'm getting is "index out of range".

Comment: `next(textfile)` will read one line of the file, effectively ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the line `next(textfile)` just before the loop. It will discard the first line from the file.

Next, you are not converting the line to intereg numbers. You only convert the *second* element, `line[1]`. The right way to convert is:

```
lst = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
```

or

```
lst = list(map(int, line.split()))
```

To summarize, your "perfect" program looks like this:

```
with open('text.txt') as infile:
    next(infile)
    for line in infile:
        lst = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add a minor correction to @DyZ answer as 
If I understand correctly, you want list `[1,2,3,4,5]` not `['1,2,3,4,5']`

```
with open('text.txt') as infile:
    next(infile)
    for line in infile:
        lst = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        print(lst)
```

If you use `line.split(',')` with `int` it will result into `ValueError - invalid literal for int()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The text file:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6 7
```

the code:

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\text.txt','r')

for line in file.readlines()[1:3]:
      lst=[int(i) for i in line.strip().split()]
      print(lst)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I'm poor in English,can't explain it with English,hope you could understand(*^__^*)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I corrected my answer @VikasDamodar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach :

```
with open('file','r') as f:
    for line_no,line in enumerate(f):
        if line_no%2==0:
            pass
        else:
            print([int(int_) for int_ in line if int_.strip()!=''])
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```